# Loading Modals with data from database

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I'm using php to create 'x' amount of buttons based on the rows from a db table.

Once the button is selected i want to pass the Variable onto the php so i can used this to load specific data from the database to the Modal.

This works for the first button click and loads the data to the modal as expected, however once i close the modal and open another modal the new userdata.php?uid=$var1 doesn't seem to get received in the php by the $var2 = $_GET['uid'] and the variable just remains the same as before.

Do i need to clear the uid in the php somehow?

The Button,

```
 $var1 = $row["Scope_ID"];

 echo "<button type='button' href='userdata.php?uid=$var1' class='btn btn-
 info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-button='$var1' data-
 target='#myModal'>$var1</button>";
```

The PHP,

```
 $var2 = $_GET['uid']; 

 echo "<h3>$var2</h3>";
```

Comment: please show the javascript that loads the data! I don't see an unique selector from which js can decide what data to send.

Comment: Hi Jeff, i'm not using any js for this each button has a different $var1 from the time it's created. To confrim this was working i named the buttons these variables to make sure it works. as i mentioned this all works for the first modal but then after that it won't pick up the new var.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is,

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#editBox').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
   });
 });
```